How to use Noto CJK with Noto and Noto Hebrew in HTML + CSS + JavaScript?
I'm trying to use Noto {Sans|Serif} CJK and Noto {Sans|Serif} and Noto {Sans|Serif|Rashi} Hebrew in a document based on HTML + CSS + JavaScript because each of them has different coverage.

However, these Noto fonts are not provided as all-in-one package due to technical reasons. The font weights of Noto Serif CJK and Noto Serif look different, but I need italic (not oblique) Latin, Greek and Cyrillic text with CJK languages and Hebrew. How should I use these fonts in a single document?
